# How can i execute php script from mysqli database

Tags: php, mysql

Please anybody help me. I want to execute php script from mysql database. My plan is so many if(),else if() statement will be execute. I had used eval($row['data']) statement in to while() loop and it's worked. But only first one.not at all.

My code as below.

```
  $conn = mysqli_connect();
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM transaction ORDER BY id ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
  eval($row['tran_php']);
 // echo eval($row['tran_php']);
 }
 }
```

Here is only first one does work which one is if(). Do you have any solution to work all about the else if() statement end of the if() statement?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Do you want to run a php script from a database management system? I don't know if that's possible, but that and the `eval` scream "bad practice" so hard, my screen is almost cracking.

Comment: Yes, you could if() the first loop, about the else end of the if() statement in the database ?!?!?  Seriously I have no clue what you are trying to do...  Maybe with sample data, what you expect it to do once out of the database, what it does today, ... ?

Comment: It looks as if you are trying to traverse your table and run the same PHP code against each line. You can do that from PHP within your mainline PHP as provided, just by calling a PHP function, surely ( e.g. { tran_php($row); } )If you are doing that from PHP, that's fine - I don't understand why you would want to call any code /from/ mysql, unless it was within a trigger perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

You have ever heared "eval is evil"? Its true. eval is a development nightmare and a good indicator for doing something wrong.

Only a idea. Do not store the PHP code in database. Store it as files, link to it in DB (filename and/or id) and include it by the regular way.

But always remember this can be a security issue if the code comes from users!

The best way is to encapsule everithing by a UI where the user inputs his stuff and PHP handles it for example by a Parser, build by you.

Why there is the need to do it with PHP-Code like you?